# Delete folder content for a folder for remote machine using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having the below code to delete the contents for folder

```
$SB_Folder = "\\$hostname\c$\SB"
$Automation_Folder = "\\$hostname\C$\Scripts\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SB_Folder -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
write-host "Content of $SB_Folder Deleted.." -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
Get-ChildItem -Path $Automation_Folder -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
write-host "Content of $Automation_Folder Deleted.." -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
```

It is executing without any error but when I check, it is not deleting all the folders.

Please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: You're not returning the folders to delete them; using `-File` specifically excludes anything that's not a file - like a folder.

Comment: Try with `Remove-Item -Path "\\$hostname\c$\SB\*" -Recurse -Force`. Same for `"\\$hostname\C$\Scripts\*"`